# GNU date command not allowing for far away years?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

When running the following command with GNU date :

```
date -d "20145-01-23"
```

I get the following result :

> date: invalid date `20145-01-23'

However, [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Calendar-date-items.html#Calendar-date-items) states that year can be any number :

> For numeric months, the ISO 8601 format ‘year-month-day’ is allowed, where year is any positive number [...]

Thus, two questions :

- is this a bug ? or am I misunderstanding something ?
- how to obtain the same behavior than BSD date, which accepts this as a valid date ?

Comment: Works for me: `date --version` says date (GNU coreutils) 8.21, and your command says `Sat Jan 23 00:00:00 PST 20145` for LC_ALL=C, POSIX and en_US.utf8.

Comment: Wow, this is crazy ! for me `date --version` says "date (GNU coreutils) 8.5", and it still tells me the invalid date message. I don't know what to think

Comment: Just thinking: can it be a crazy regional format, such that date assumes `23` as month? Try `LC_ALL=C date -d "20145-01-23"`.

Comment: @LarsFischer thanks, I tried it but got the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me, using GNU coreutils 8.24:

```
$ date -d "20145-01-23"
Sat Jan 23 00:00:00 PST 20145
```

I'm not certain of this explanation (***UPDATE:*** *looks like my guess was correct*), but my guess is that you're on a system with a 32-bit `time_t` rather than 64 bits.  With 32 bits, the only representable dates are from Fri 1901-12-13 20:45:52 UTC (2<sup>31</sup> seconds before the epoch) to Tue 2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC (2<sup>31</sup>-1 seconds after the epoch).

If this is the case, then this command should succeed:

```
$ date -d 2037-01-01
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 PST 2037
```

and this one should fail:

```
$ date -d 2039-01-01
date: invalid date ‘2039-01-01’
```

(I've reconstructed what the result should look like for that last command. The output of the first will vary slightly depending on your time zone.)

> how to obtain the same behavior than BSD date, which accepts this as a valid date ?

Are you saying you *want* BSD date to reject it? If so (more speculation), either run a 32-bit version of BSD, or test whether the requested time is outside the 32-bit range of timestamps.

Comment: You nailed it ! Impressive ! Wonder how you managed to think about this !

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew: I've worked on plenty of 32-bit and 64-bit systems, and I know that the maximum value of `time_t` when it's a signed 32-bit integer representing seconds since 1970 is some time in February 2038. Googling "2038" will turn up a lot of results discussing that.

Comment: A thing to note for ancient dates: before the Gregorian calendar there was only the Julian, so the name of weekday will be wrong. E.g.: `date -d "0001-01-23"` prints `Tue Jan 23 00:00:00 CET 0001`, but that's "fake" Gregorian. In the Julian calendar then in effect that date fell on a Sunday; see: http://fourmilab.ch/documents/calendar/#juliancalendar … I've always tried to find a command line date program to handle ancient dates that respects the switch from Gregorian to Julian, and that also extends to BCE. Couldn't find anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

BSD `date -d` expects a time zone value. To offset years, days, or whatever, you pass -v*NT*, where N is a number and T is a char to indicate days, months, or years.

The flags differ. See http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/1/date/ for the Gnu version, http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/date/ for a common BSD variant.

Comment: Always helpful to remember what GNU actually stands for; **G**NU's **N**ot **U**nix. BSD *is*.

Comment: I know the flags differ. What I meant is that BSD date doesn't reject 20145-01-23 as a valid date

Comment: What output do you get using BSD date, from the above?

Comment: if I run `date -ujf"%Y-%m-%d" "20145-01-23" "+%Y-%m-%d"` I get `20145-01-23` and that's it